# How to find the area of intersection of two circles using axiomatic geometry?

Tags: circles, area, axiomatic-geometry

**Problem**: square(ABCD) is a regular square, and a circle touches internally in the square.
Also, arc(BD) divides the square. Then calculate the area of the colored region.

[image]

This question is easily solved when you use analytical geometry. But  I can't solve it by only using axiomatic geometry. How to solve this by not using analytical geometry?

Comment: What is the 'colored point'?

Comment: I suppose the 'colored region'

Comment: Many people thinks it is unclear...umm.

Comment: You must improve the question. (For example, you can make the question clearly.) If you modify the question properly, the question will be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

I'm referring to the following figure:

[image]

The area in question can be viewed as the  formal sum of two circular sectors minus two triangles.

Note that $$b={a\over2}, \quad c={a\over\sqrt{2}}\ ,$$
and the cosine theorem allows to compute the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$\cos\alpha={b^2+c^2-a^2\over 2 bc}=-{\sqrt{2}\over4},\qquad \cos\beta={a^2+c^2-b^2\over 2ac}={5\sqrt{2}\over 8}\ .$$
The areas of the two circular sectors are then given by
$$A_\alpha={b^2\over2}\cdot2\alpha={\alpha\over4}a^2,\qquad A_\beta={a^2\over2}\cdot 2\beta=\beta a^2\,$$
and the area of one triangle is given by
$$A_\triangle={1\over2}ac\>\sin\beta={\sqrt{7}\over16}a^2\ .$$
Therefore the shaded area comes to
$$A=A_\alpha+A_\beta-2A_\triangle=\left({1\over4}\arccos{-\sqrt{2}\over4}+\arccos{5\sqrt{2}\over8}-{\sqrt{7}\over8}\right)a^2\doteq0.639\>a^2\ .$$